# Concurrently reading messages from IBM MQs using python

Tags: python, concurrency, pymqi

As part of a project, we have to read messages from multiple IBM queues using python.
For connecting to message queues, we are using pymqi library.

There are around 2-3 queue managers containing a total of 45-50 queues. The expectation is to read messages concurrently from all queues as and when any message is available. Any solution without an additional layer of infrastructure is desired.

Multiprocessing was thought about but no of queues can increase in future. So did not go ahead with it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.